# If A is nowhere dense in M, and if G is a nonempty open set in M, prove that A is nowhere dense in G.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, baire-category

If A is nowhere dense in M, and if G is a nonempty open set in M, prove that
A is nowhere dense in G.

I tried by contradiction but could not figure it out. I found that we can use following result 
Given a subset S of a topological space Z, the following are equivalent:

S is nowhere dense in Z.
For every non-empty open V⊆Z, there is a non-empty open W⊆V such that S∩W=∅.
how to prove this result and apply in our context.

Comment: What did you mean by "$A$ is nowhere dense in $G$"? is it $G\backslash \overline{A}$ is dense in $G$?

Comment: A set $V \subset G$ is open in $G$ implies $V$ is open in $M$ as $G$ is open.

Comment: Could you please explain me more details @ sinbadh and Hetebrij

Answer (score 1):

Use the equivalence at the end of your question and the fact that if $V\subseteq G$ is open in $G$, then $V$ is also open in $M$, since $G$ is open in $M$.

Let $V$ be a non-empty open subset of $G$. $G$ is open in $M$, so $V$ is open in $M$. $A$ is nowhere dense in $M$, so there is a non-empty open $W\subseteq V$ such that $A\cap W=\varnothing$. Thus, every non-empty open subset of $G$ has a non-empty open subset disjoint from $A$, so $A$ is nowhere dense in $G$.